# How to get the complete URL from URI?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to get the path or a URL I intercept from my app.

Sample URL: `http://myapp.com/foo/bar/145`

I am trying to get: `/foo/bar/145`

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String path = data.getPath() // gives "/"
```

How can I get `/foo/bar/145`?

Comment: This is a rather vague question. Can you post more informations or be clearer? This is not an Android or intent question right? Is it merely a Java-String parsing question?

Comment: This is an android question not java string parsing. I am trying to get a string out of the `Uri` API which resembles `/foo/bar/145` part of my `http://myapp.com/foo/bar/145`

Answer (score 7):

`.toString()` method will return complete url as a simple String, if you need URL instance, then you can use `new URL(uriPath.toString())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using , Iam able to get `/foo/bar/145`

`uri.getEncodedPath()`

Answer (score 0):

You will get the entire path using:

Java:

```
String url = "https://" + uri.getHost() + uri.getEncodedPath();
```

Kotlin:

```
val url =  "https://${uri.host}${uri.encodedPath}"
```